# Find the solution of the IVP

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

> Reduce the following initial-value problem to one involving a first-order linear differential equation system
> $$y'''-y'' + y'-y=\sec{t}; y(0)=2, y'(0)=-1, y''(0)=1$$
> then find the corresponding fundamental matrix and solve the above linear differential equation

I found out the fundamental matrix as it was easy **but finding the solution of the system is what I need help with**.

The system I found out is
$$Y'(t)=\begin{bmatrix}y_1'(t)\\y_2'(t)\\y_3'(t)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1&  0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\1 & -1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}y_1(t)\\y_2(t)\\y_3(t)\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\\sec{t}\end{bmatrix} \tag1$$

and, the Fundamental matrix is
$$\psi(t)=\begin{bmatrix}e^t&-e^{\iota t}& -e^{-\iota t} \\ e^t & -\iota e^{\iota t} & \iota e^{-\iota t} \\ e^t & e^{\iota t}& e^{-\iota t}\end{bmatrix}$$

But when I suppose that the solution of $(1)$ is
$$\psi(t)C(t)=\begin{bmatrix}e^t&-e^{\iota t}& -e^{-\iota t} \\ e^t & -\iota e^{\iota t} & \iota e^{-\iota t} \\ e^t & e^{\iota t}& e^{-\iota t}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}C_1(t)\\C_2(t)\\C_3(t)\end{bmatrix}$$ the relations become ugly and I'm unable to solve, help!!!

Comment: I think the correct system matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1&  0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\1 & -1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, because most likely you used the parametrization $y_1=y,y_2=y_1',y_3=y_2'$ and then $y_3'$ can be obtained through differential equation.

Comment: @K.K.McDonald yes sorry I typed it wrong. You wrote it correctly

Comment: @Moo Now I edited it, actually I typed it wrong. Yes the initial conditions are given as I typed

Comment: @Moo yes it is written as it is and my solution is also very ugly can you please share your solution ?